# Selecting types for an Array extension

Tags: swift, types, collections, protocols, extension-methods

I'm trying to extend the `Array.contains` function to allow an optional parameter and return false when the parameter is nil. I started with this:

```
extension Array {
    func contains(_ element: Element?) -> Bool {
        if let element = element {
            return self.contains(element)
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

When the argument is nil, the calling code correctly finds my version of the function. However, the `self.contains` inside this function doesn't call the original version -- it calls itself and creates an infinite loop. Is there a way make the `self.contains` line call the original function?

Next, I tried replacing `self.contains` with a different implementation, but I couldn't think of anything that didn't require constraining the extension to `Element: Equatable`, like this:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func contains(_ element: Element?) -> Bool {
        if let element = element {
            return (self.firstIindex(of: element) != nil)
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

However, that makes the function unavailable to element types like UIButton, Dictionary and other things I need to use it with. How does the original `contains` function do this for these types? (I searched and couldn't find the source code for it.)

Next, I removed the constraint and changed the method signature to disambiguate between my extension function and the original function:

```
extension Array {
    func contains(optional element: Element?) -> Bool {
        if let element = optional {
            return self.contains(element)
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

But when I change the method signature, a compiler error tells me that the `self.contains` line now requires Element to conform to Equatable.
How is the original function exempt from this limitation, while a function with a slightly different signature requires it?

I feel like this should be trivial, but I've spent hours on it and can't find a working setup. Can someone show me a solution?

Comment: "How is the original function exempt from this limitation?" It isn't... See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains). Note the wording: "Available when Element conforms to Equatable."

Comment: Also note: `UIButton` and `Dictionary` both conform to `Equatable`.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing @Sweeper's comment about UIButton and Dictionary being equatable, I tried again with that constraint. I was seeing errors before with arrays of UIButtons, but not this time, so those must have been triggered by something else. However, the errors with what I thought were Dictionaries were actually just plain structs. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51280079/462162) to make my structs comform to Equatable, and now everything works as intended.

In fact, with the Equatable constraint added, the infinite loop no longer occurs, so I can go back to the first version of my function:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func contains(_ element: Element?) -> Bool {
        if let element = element {
            return self.contains(element)
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently there is a version of `contains()` that doesn't have the Equatable constraint, which is what I was calling when using structs before, and what my custom function was calling with `self.contains()`. Anyway, these are the lessons learned:

1. When creating a variation of a native function, add the same type constraints as the original.
2. Conform custom structs to Equatable for ease of use with collections.